# Arc Lengths in $2$-D

Tags: calculus

Suppose you have a curve $y=f(x)$, then is it possible to find a curve $f$ on which the distance between two points is shorter when one travels along the curve compared to the rectilinear distance.

In other words does there exist a curve $f(x)$ such that arc length is shorter than the distance between two points?

Comment: Please don't use abbreviations like that. The time it takes you to type out "standard" stands in no relation to the total time it takes your dozens or hundreds of readers to think about what you might mean by "st.".

Comment: I think it was strait not standard

Comment: @Quality: You may well be right. That reinforces my point :-)

Comment: More likely "straight".

Comment: It can be proven that for two fixed points in the plane. The path which minimizes the distance between the two points is a straight line. You should look into the Calculus of Variations. This is a huge subject which I like to think of as optimization with an infinite number of degrees of freedom, most texts that I know of have as one of their first examples the question that you have posed.

Comment: @Tucker: Why does everyone say we need calculus of variations? You have a continuous path from one point to another and want to minimize the supremum of the sum of segment lengths over all partitions. Clearly there must be no point outside the direct straight path otherwise the direct path wins. Therefore the direct path is the shortest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such curve. In fact the shortest arc length of any curve joining two points is one of the possible definitions of the distance between two points.